# Rails 4 - how to write a scope to exclude one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I'm trying to learn how to write scopes in my Rails 4 app.

I have models called User, Profile, Project and Potential Uses. The associations are:

User

```
has_one :profile
has_many :potential_uses
```

Profile

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :projects
```

Project

```
belongs_to :profile
has_many :potential_uses
```

Potential Uses

```
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
```

I have attributes in my Potential Use table for:

```
:comment
:internal_comments_permitted
:external_comments_permitted
```

I have scopes in my potential uses model for:

```
scope :internal_comments_permitted, ->  where(:internal_comments_permitted => 'true')
    scope :external_comments_permitted, ->  where(:external_comments_permitted => 'true')
```

I then have a class method for finding all of the third party comments:

```
def third_party_comments
  self.internal_comments_permitted.external_comments_permitted
end
```

Now, I'm trying to write a scope to exclude any comment made by the user who has the profile that the project belongs to, from the group of third party comments.

I want to have a view page that shows third party comments separately from the project creator's comments.

```
scope :third_party_comments, -> where(:comment.user_id != potential_uses.project.profile.user_id)
```

I know the above isn't right, but I can't figure out what's wrong with this attempt.

**Taking Hasmukh's suggestion with the tweak from Ninigi:**

```
scope :third_party_comments, ->(potential_uses.project.profile.user_id) { where.not(comments: {user_id: potential_uses.project.profile.user_id} ) }
```

but this gives an error that says:

```
syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'
...ty_comments, ->(potential_uses.project.profile.user_id) { wh...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
scope :third_party_comments, ->where.not(comment.user_id: potential_uses.project.profile.user_id)
```

Reference: [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions)

Comment: @Hasmukh_Rathod. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but it seems to have an error somewhere in it: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting keyword_do_LAMBDA or tLAMBEG
...third_party_comments, -> where.not(comment.user_id: potentia...

Comment: Can you see what's wrong? I don't know what tLAMBEG means

Comment: There should not be any space between -> and where.not clause. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that too. It then gives an error message with: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting keyword_do_LAMBDA or tLAMBEG

Comment: I then tried putting the whole where statement inside {}, but then the error message is: syntax error, unexpected ':'
..., ->{where.not(comment.user_id: potential_uses.project.profi...

Comment: scope :third_party_comments, ->(potential_uses.project.profile.user_id) { where.not(comment.user_id: potential_uses.project.profile.user_id) }

Comment: @Mel `comment.user_id:` the key: syntax is only usable with single words, you will either have to use `comments.user_id" => ` or `comments: { user_id: ... }`

Comment: The last attempt gives this error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'
...ty_comments, ->(potential_uses.project.profile.user_id) { wh...
...

Comment: @Ninigi - I tried your suggestion and posted the attempt in the post above. But it still gives an error that says: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'
...ty_comments, ->(potential_uses.project.profile.user_id) { wh...

Comment: To make this work, you probably need to surround the where-clause in braces... eg `scope :third_party_comments, -> { where.not(comment.user_id: potential_uses.project.profile.user_id) }` - all scopes now have to be a lambda this way.

Comment: @TarynEast - syntax error, unexpected ':'
...-> { where.not(comment.user_id: potential_uses.project.profi...
...

Comment: @TarynEast - I think user Ninigi thinks you can't chain multiple words together in a scope. I tried taking that advice in this construct, but still get an error

Comment: ah fair enough - you need to fix that too... but the lambda-error is about the fact that it isn't a lambda (and needs to have braces to become one)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

```
scope :third_party_comments, -> where(:comment.user_id != potential_uses.project.profile.user_id)
```

`where` takes a hash or an array of SQL fragments, but you've kinda got a conditional instead. 
So you can't quite do it as above, but you can use SQL fragments eg try:

```
scope :third_party_comments, -> { where("comment.user_id <> ?",  potential_uses.project.profile.user_id) }
```

This uses the array-syntax of Rails - the first item is a small chunk of pure SQL - which uses `<>` to mean "not equal to" and uses the question-mark to indicate 'the second value goes here' (but in a safely sanitised way)

Note: not bug-tested, may need some minor jiggering to make it work... I'd check out the Rails Guide on the Query interface for more detail of what you can and can't do: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

(In fact I strongly recommend reading though all the Rails Guides as a way to level-up on how Rails works).

I've also updated the scope to add braces around the lambda - which is recommended for Rails scopes these days.

Comment: @Taryn_East Thanks for this suggestion. I have read all of the guides a few times. I just re-read the Active Record Query Interface guide - I can't find anything in the guide that explains what the  first hash in the where () means. What does '<>' do or mean? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I tried the suggestion. I get an error (for which I haven't yet figured out how to translate into english): syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_do_LAMBDA or tLAMBEG
...third_party_comments, -> where("comment.user_id <> ?",  pote...
...